# How to disable @typescript-eslint/no-require-imports in xo

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, lint, typescript-eslint

I tried [xojs/xo](https://github.com/xojs/xo) today, got a problem about `@typescript-eslint/no-require-imports` I cant disable it.

I tried this config but no avail

```
  "xo": {
    "rules": {
      "@typescript-eslint/no-require-imports": false
    }
  },
```

Anyone, what is the proper way to exclude some rules in `xo`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find solution with this. Just added the  config to eslintConfig in package.json.

I came up with this.

```json
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "xo",
      "xo-typescript"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "@typescript-eslint/no-require-imports": "off"
    }
  },
  "xo": {
    "rules": {
      "@typescript-eslint/no-require-imports": 0
    }
  },
```

The rules under `eslintConfig` will the editor linter to ignore the error, while the rules under `xo` will ignore if execute `xo`.